# Website or application for travel recommendations?

Tags: online-resources, planning, destinations, mobile-apps

When looking for new destinations to travel to, I'm usually reading blogs in the Internet, browse through Travel SE or rely on recommendations of friends. But is there a more active way of finding a suitable travel destination?

I'm looking for a website or application that allows me to enter queries in the following form:

> I want to do a lot of sightseeing, a little bis of adventure, spend
>   $1000, want to stay for 2 weeks, reach it in 2 hours from Switzerland.

And then get a recommendation of feasible destinations. Is there anything like this available?

Comment: There is a spanish website, that could fit your requirements, but has a problem: you need to speak spanish and (maybe, I have not tried) start your trip from Spain: http://www.buscounviaje.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [HappyTellus destination finder](http://www.happytellus.com/asearch.php) comes very close to what you are looking for.

It has no option for the budget. I think it used to have one, but I never found it very useful. Budget is something very stretchy. It depends a lot on what you want to spend. Or put differently, you can control it, at least partially, by appropriately choosing mode for travel, accommodation, catering, etc.

Depending on the type of traveler you are, you can also try sites like ltur.com. There you specify a point of departure, and you can search according to regions and budget.

Answer (score 3):

[Flyertalk.com](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/europe-477/) has forums regarding many countries and regions around the world - might be a good start for you, based on your two-hour requirement (by flight?).  Although you have to become a member to post a question, you don't need to become one just to read through the threads.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Wanderfly](http://www.wanderfly.com/) which you can plan trips based on your budget and interests.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying Wander which allows you to search for travel destinations according to your budget, availability and other preferences you might have.

[Wander - Search for travel destinations](http://www.wanderapp.me?ref=stack_ex)

[image: Wander - travel search engine]